# Reading String in a single line if there is an integer too in that line

Tags: java

Read an integer and a string provided in a single line in JAVA.
INPUT

```
3 ABCDEF
```

how to store 3 in a integer variable and ABCDEF in a string variable

Comment: Are the number and the non-numerical characters always seperated by a space, or not?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. You could for example use str = line.split(" "). It will give you 2 strings in an array, the first is your number (which you can extract with Integer.parseInt(str0]).

Comment: google can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = scanner.nextInt();
String text = scanner.next();
```

If you already have the data in a `String`, pass this `String` variable as the constructor of your `Scanner`:

```
String foo = "123 ABCDE";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(foo);
int number = scanner.nextInt();
String text = scanner.next();
```

If you want/need more info about it, read the proper javadoc.

Comment: I think it's not that he want.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mixData="123 string";
        String []data = mixData.split("\\s+", 2);
        int intValue=Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        String str=data[1];
        System.out.println(intValue);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: Use `mixData.split("\\s+", 2)` to assure you will only get 2 elements after splitting the string.